# What does <fd-35> mean on Vimgolf?

Tags: vim

I'm trying to improve my Vim skills through VimGolf (http://www.vimgolf.com/) and I can't seem to figure out what the sequence `<fd-35>` means. [Here's an example](http://www.vimgolf.com/challenges/4d1a1c36567bac34a9000002#4d1b5a82c58eaa2a8a000697).

Thanks

Answer (score 16, accepted):

It appears to be an artefact of the way that vimgolf is often 'played'.  See this [posting on the vimdev](http://comments.gmane.org/gmane.editors.vim.devel/29345) list.

In summary: golfers use

```
 vim -u /dev/null -N -W foo
```

to record their efforts.  When running in an xterm or similar, vim start-up automatically tries to set some options in the terminal, and these end up rendered in the log file as a 'spurious' prefix.

Comment: Ah! Thanks, it was driving me crazy trying to figure out which key combination that represented.

Comment: So, is it totally inert? How do you interpret such a sequence if you see it in a solution? I haven't seen any that are prefixes, but I've seen at least one where `<fd-56>` seems to be replacing a `G` in `gwG`: http://vimgolf.com/challenges/50ad2cb165b8db0002000029#50af43c932b7ed000200005e